# Spark Structured Streaming - cannot resolve "Kafka" format (Jupyter notebook on Cloudera cluster)

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook, cloudera, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run a sample **Spark Structured Streaming** app using **Juputer notebook** (**PySpark** kernel) on my **Cloudera** cluster, however it seems I cannot make it use the required package.

```
dsraw = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafkaBroker:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "test") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()
```

Error I am getting:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o113.load.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
```

My setup:

- Spark version: '2.4.0.cloudera2'
- Scala version: 2.11.12
- Kafka version: 2.1.0-kafka-4.0.0

My attempts:

1) Edit kernel.json

```
"PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": " --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 --master yarn --deploy-mode client pyspark-shell"
```

2) passing environment variables in the code

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 pyspark-shell'
```

When I run pyspark from command line it seems to work, but I am facing different issues when trying to query a stream (I need to make it work from Jupyter anyway)

```
pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0
```

I am familiar with the [integration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html), however in my case this seems to be not sufficient.

I was also trying with different versions of the package, also tried passing it as a jar. Do you have any ideas what could be wrong? Is it Cloudera distribution or Jupyter-specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

Good night friend, I have a problem similar to yours... but this step of the package I solved by putting it like this:

```
pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1
```

This is due to the version of spark/pyspark so I managed to get readStream to work.

My problem now is that I can't write or print the data.values ​​using the Registry schema, were you able to go ahead with that? if you can, it will help a lot.

example of my code:

```
schemaRegistryUrl = "http://localhost:8081"
df = spark \
.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
.option("subscribe", "topic-a") \
.load() \
.select(from_avro(col("value"), schemaRegistryUrl).alias("values"))
```

Comment: thanks for the comment - unfortunately, I've not got back to this topic since then, good luck!